# VB.NET Trying to use C++/CLR class but it doesn't exist in VB

Tags: vb.net, c++-cli, clr

I'm trying to create a C++/CLR project to allow me to use the SendARP method from iphlpapi.dll. I have created the CLR project in my solution and added a reference on my VB project to the DLL produced by it. I then have the following header files:

## Wrapper.h

```
#include "IPHelper.h"
#include <IPHlpApi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

public ref class NativeClassWrapper {
    IPHelper* m_nativeClass;

public:
    NativeClassWrapper() { m_nativeClass = new IPHelper(); }
    ~NativeClassWrapper() { this->!NativeClassWrapper(); }
    !NativeClassWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }

    void TestMethod() {
        m_nativeClass->TestMethod();
    }

};
```

## IPHelper.h

```
#pragma once

public class IPHelper {
public:
    void TestMethod();

};
```

I'm trying the following in my VB project but the class doesn't exist

```
Dim test As New NativeClassWrapper
```

Comment: You should check the DLL with *IL Disassembler*, that could tell you whether the problem is in the C++/CLI project or the VB.Net one.

Comment: What namespace is that class a member of?  Have you imported that namespace in your VB project?  If not then you would need to qualify the class name.

Comment: Disassembling is the right approach to debugging this, but dotPeek or .NET Reflector would be more user-friendly than `ildasm`.

Comment: Is that header file included into a .cpp file in the C++/CLI project?  Header files never get compiled by themselves.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I had forgotten to include the header in the .cpp file lol.